# Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) share task

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to use simple share task on my WP8.1 app (WinRT). The code for Silverlight would be like this

```
ShareStatusTask share = new ShareStatusTask();
share.Status = "some text";
hare.Show();
```

but it doesn't work on winRT. So basicly I need to call that app picker to choose which app you want to share your string. Any ideas?

Comment: See the sharing documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871374.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8.1
Share
The new way of sharing is like the one in Windows store apps. Windows can ask the program if it has anything to share, and what that might be. For this you need to implement a function in your views which can share and set it in the DataTransferManager. A complete code might look like:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Register the current page as a share source.
    _dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    _dataTransferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Unregister the current page as a share source.
    _dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;
}

protected void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "Some title";
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "Some description"; // Optional 
    e.Request.Data.SetUri(new Uri("http://www.some_uri.com"));
}
In the example we use the SetUri to share an Uri. There are many different shares which is used to share different things:

 SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference value)

SetApplicationLink(Uri value)

SetData(string formatId, object value)

SetDataProvider(string formatId, DataProviderHandler delayRenderer)

SetStorageItems(IEnumerable value)

SetStorageItems(IEnumerable value, bool readOnly)

SetText(string value)

SetUri(Uri value)

SetWebLink(Uri value)

SetHtmlFormat(string value)

SetRtf(string value)
```

If the OnDataRequested will take a little time you can use deferral to tell the operating system that your app has not stopped working. You can also call the share view from code to show it. Example if you have share in a menu and want to show it when user selects it. When you have to call this function from somewhere:

DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();